# Magic square in python

Tags: python, while-loop, magic-square

I'm new to coding. I'm trying to program a magic square. A magic square is a square (3 × 3 for my case, could be different), where all rows and columns and diagonals must sum to a certain number (15 for my case, because of the 3 × 3). Here is my code:

```
s = []
while len(s) < 9:
    n = 0
    a = random.randrange(1, 10)
    while a not in s:
        s.append(a)


while s[0] + s[1] + s[2] != 15 and s[3] + s[4] + s[5] != 15 and \
        s[6] + s[7] + s[8] != 15 and s[0] + s[4] + s[8] != 15 \
        and s[2] + s[4] + s[6] != 15 and s[0] + s[3] + s[6] != 15 and \
        s[1] + s[4] + s[7] != 15 and s[2] + s[5] + s[8] != 15:
    shuffle(s)
print(s)
```

I don't understand why the program isn't shuffling until all the criteria are met in the while loop. I know this is not the way to code this program and even if it would work, it would be randomness and brute forcing the solution, i would just like to understand what is happening inside the while loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've written the condition of your loop incorrectly. It currently requires that *none* of the rows, columns or diagonals add up to the right value. If any of them do, it quits, since the chained `and`s result in a `False` value.

Instead, I think you want to use the `or` operator instead of the `and` operator. That way you'd keep looping as long as *any* of the conditions was true (meaning any of the lines didn't add up correctly).

Or alternatively, you could keep the `and` operators, but change the `!=` operators to `==` and negate the whole thing at the end (since `not X or not Y` is logically equivalent to `not (X and Y)`):

```
while not (s[0] + s[1] + s[2] == 15 and s[3] + s[4] + s[5] == 15 and 
           s[6] + s[7] + s[8] == 15 and s[0] + s[4] + s[8] == 15 and
           s[2] + s[4] + s[6] == 15 and s[0] + s[3] + s[6] == 15 and
           s[1] + s[4] + s[7] == 15 and s[2] + s[5] + s[8] == 15):
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, yes you are right, as soon as the first criteria is met, the while loop stops because it required all of the criteria to be met at the same time, but we just solved a criteria...so it didn't shuffle anymore. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to replace your 'ands' with 'ors'. The program is terminating as soon as the first condition is met because logically the way that you have written it all of those conditions need to be met for it to continue. Also, while not strictly necessary, I've generally found that the brackets around individual logic conditions tend to help.

```
s = []
while len(s) < 9:
    n = 0
    a = random.randrange(1, 10)
    while a not in s:
        s.append(a)


while (s[0] + s[1] + s[2] != 15) or (s[3] + s[4] + s[5] != 15) or \
    (s[6] + s[7] + s[8] != 15) or (s[0] + s[4] + s[8] != 15) \
    or (s[2] + s[4] + s[6] != 15) or (s[0] + s[3] + s[6] != 15) or \
    (s[1] + s[4] + s[7] != 15) or (s[2] + s[5] + s[8] != 15):
    shuffle(s)
print(s)
```

Comment: Please show an example of how it will with ORs as answers with no examples attract downvotes.

Comment: Thank you so much, yes reading your comment i just realized as soon the first criteria is met it stops because then the while is not 'activated' anymore (1 criteria is missing)